# Get unique values from rows with comma separated values based on a specific category column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

Lets say I have:

```
group     X                 Y                   Z
A         cat, dog          dog, fox        
A         fox, chicken      dog, fox, chicken
A
B         fox, dog 
B         fox
B                                               bunny
```

I want to summarize unique animals per group based on these three columns, as

```
group     animal
A         cat, dog, fox, chicken
B         bunny, dog, fox
```

The order of animals doens't matter, as long as they are the unique values.
I tried:

```
df %>%  
group_by(group) %>% 
separate_rows("X", sep=",")   %>%  
distinct %>%    
summarise(X = toString(X))
```

Which does not work even for one column (I get a bunch of NAs)

I was thinking something such as

```
df %>%   group_by(group) %>%   summarise_at(vars("X","Y","Z"), sum)
```

Which works for numerical variables not separated by comma (one value per row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
df %>%
   pivot_longer(-group)%>%
   separate_rows(value)%>%
   summarise(animal = toString(unique(value[nzchar(value)])), .by = group)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  group animal                
  <chr> <chr>                 
1 A     cat, dog, fox, chicken
2 B     fox, dog, bunny
```

In base R you could do:

```
fn <- function(x) {
  toString(unique(scan(text=x, what="", sep=',', strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)))
}
aggregate(values~group, cbind(df[1], stack(df,-1)), fn)

  group                 values
1     A cat, dog, fox, chicken
2     B        fox, dog, bunny
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way (it presupposes that the empty cells are `NA`):

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate_rows(-group) %>%
  pivot_longer(-group, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(value = str_c(unique(value), collapse = ", "))
```

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  X = c("cat, dog", "chicken","fox, dog", "fox"),
  Y = c("dog, fox", "fox, dog", NA, NA),
  Z = c(NA, NA, "bunny", NA)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also `unite`, then split on ",", then finally concatenate the `unique` values

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df |> 
    unite("animals",
          c(X, Y, Z),
          sep = ",",
          remove = TRUE,
          na.rm = TRUE
          ) |> 
    summarise(animals = str_split(animals, ",\\s*") |> 
                  unlist() |> 
                  unique() |> 
                  toString(),
              .by = group
              )

  group                animals
1     A cat, dog, fox, chicken
2     B        fox, dog, bunny
```